# Server Side Google Tag Manager eCommerce event not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

I have been banging my heads for couple of hours here... tried many things still not working! I don't know why but everything is setup correctly...

Here tag is firing from my website...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here in debug view I see page_view but not my add_to_cart event... none event shows up in here, purchase, product view, nothing!!?? Why none event shows up but page_view does?

```
dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });  // Clear the previous ecommerce object.
dataLayer.push({
  event: "add_to_cart",
  ecommerce: {
    currency: "USD",
    value: 7.77,
    items: [
    {
      item_id: "SKU_12345",
      item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
      affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
      coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
      discount: 2.22,
      index: 0,
      item_brand: "Google",
      item_category: "Apparel",
      item_category2: "Adult",
      item_category3: "Shirts",
      item_category4: "Crew",
      item_category5: "Short sleeve",
      item_list_id: "related_products",
      item_list_name: "Related Products",
      item_variant: "green",
      location_id: "ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo",
      price: 9.99,
      quantity: 1
    }
    ]
  }
});
```

This is a server side GTM tagging with GA4 Google Analytics!! Please anyone help what am I doing wrong... Thanks

Comment: How do you test this? Do you have preview mode in Web GTM and Server GTM enabled at the same time during testing?

Comment: 1- You have not set the configuration tag.

2-  Do not use {{Event}} as the Event Name, instead write the actual event's name, for example if you are using a customised event named "customised_tracker", simply write this name (the event name should be the exact name which you have used in your front-end code).

3- Have you created the custom dimensions in your analytics.google profile? I see you have Event Parameters, are these dimensions and the value assigned to them created?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to debug:

1. Click on the GA4 - Add to Cart tag in preview mode. At the top right of the popup click "values". This will show you all values being extracted and sent in the payload to GA4. If they're present and of correct value, then good. But if null, then that could be the first issue.
2. Click on "variables" tab in preview mode for that event, this will show the values of the variables being extracted for the event. Make sure the values are present.

Things to consider:

1. GA4 does have latency issues. Please do not fully rely on real-time reports as sometimes some events could fly under the radar. Instead, as a test, send an additional parameter, maybe "test" with the value of "true" and rerun this instance. Check back in historic reports in 24-48 hours to see if you can confirm an event with that test parameter.
2. Make sure you're still sending a configuration/set up tag before this event tag is firing. I'm not sure on the context of this situation because you're only showing the "add to cart" event, but if you click on "summary" tab in preview mode make sure "GA4 - Config" is firing in one of the iteratives before the event fires.

Hope this helps!